# Ajax enabled wcf service doesnt seem to work for me

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf

I have a web application that uses ajax enabled wcf service `Service.scv`.... I got it working yesterday... But when i ran my application now... It gives me error

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

When inspected through firebug i saw this,

```
http://localhost:1482/CR-F/Service.svc/js 500 Internal Server Error
```

Why is it happening am i missing something... Any suggestion...

**EDIT:**

Deleting temporary ASP.Net files solved the prob....

Is it a long term fix...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

```
<compilation debug="false" batch="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this on dev machine and deleting temp files fixed it... Also a great tool to help diagnose wcf (especially calling from ajax where 500 Server Error is not much use) is to use SvcTraceViewer.exe. For example in this instance the logs would have pointed you to the temp asp.net folders...

http://www.dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Diagnosing-WCF-Problems-Using-SvcTraceViewerexe.aspx