# 406 Not Acceptable error when using Jquery $.post in Firefox but not in Safari or Chrome

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, firefox

I'm using Jquery (1.3.2)  $.post command to trigger an ajax call to a rails server.

The code works great on Safari and on Google Chrome (mac), but when I tried it on Firefox (3.5.7), I got a weird '406 Not Acceptable' error.

When I look at the headers, it Firefox indicated that it accepted only '    text/javascript' responses. And the response Content-Type    was 'text/html; charset=utf-8'.

In Chrome the accepted types were 'application/json, text/javascript, */*, text/javascript' and the response Content-Type was 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.

I tried to force the content type in rails to 'text/javascript'

```
format.json do
   render :json => @races.to_json, :content_type => 'text/javascript'
end
```

The content type is indeed changed in Chrome, but not in Firefox where it remains 'text/html'.

Here is the code I used to trigger the ajax call.

```
$.post(
    "/locator",
    params, 
    function(data){...},
    "json"
);
```

Is there something I can do to make this work in Firefox?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a .json extension to your URL in the post call

```
$.post(
"/locator.json"
...
```

Or (possibly better) add the following to your application.js to set headers for all ajax requests

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")} 
})
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.
The jQuery.ajaxSetup didn't provide any help, but I followed your first reply. 
I created a specific route in rails dedicated to the ajax call
ajaxlocator.json and it now works fine !
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. It seems to be a firefox issue.

This works:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript,application/javascript,text/html")} })
```

[Credit goes to this blog.](http://www.workingasintended.com/blog/2009/08/10/firefox-3-5-2-and-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader/)

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Comment: This is a much better answer for me; setting a global option that simply takes care of Firefox! I had Paul Groves' jQuery.ajaxSetup already in my application.js, but this amended one does it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense that different browsers see different HTTP headers. Perhaps this is a caching issue.

Comment: @Kgiannakakis please suggest me a solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242418/inheriting-baseclass-to-an-ajax-enabled-wcf-service-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242788/ajax-enabled-wcf-service-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-me

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the contentType option during the $.ajaxSetup call to set the content type explicitly. That work's across browsers:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

None of the above suggestions (atmorell, Paul Groves) fixed it for me... then I found [jquery $.ajax not working in firefox against rails (406 response) (works in chrome & IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505200/jquery-ajax-not-working-in-firefox-against-rails-406-response-works-in-chrom)

As I commented there, the accepted answer worked! (using format.js rather than format.json, and "render :text => item.to_json")

For the record, I'm not making a straight .ajax call; rather I'm using JQuery.UI's autocompleter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#task_summary_task_wbs").autocomplete({
        source: "/tasks/summary.js"
    });
});
```

and this in my TasksController:

```
# GET /tasks/summary.js
def summary
  @tasks = Task.find(:all,
                     :conditions => ['is_summary = true AND wbs like ?',
                                     "%#{params[:term]}%"],
                     :order => :wbs)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
      render :text => @tasks.collect {|t| t.wbs_name}.to_json
    }
  end
end
```

a la Railscast #102.