# jquery $.ajax not working in firefox against rails (406 response) (works in chrome & IE)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails backend and am testing the following jquery code against it:

```
  var content = $("#notification_content").val();
  var data = new Object();
  data.content = content;
  $.ajax({ url: "/notifications/detect_type.json", type:"POST", data: data, success: function(result  ){updateTypeDropDown(result)}});
```

This code works fine in Chrome and IE.  However in Firefox (using Firebug), I see this:
http://localhost:3000/notifications/detect_type.json  406 Not Acceptable

**here is a firefox request in the log:**

> Processing
>   NotificationsController#detect_type
>   (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-21 17:05:59)
>   [POST]   Parameters:
>   {"action"=>"detect_type",
>   "content"=>"226 south emerson denver
>   co 80209",
>   "controller"=>"notifications"}   User
>   Columns (2.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM
>   `users`   User Load (37.4ms)   SELECT
>   * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = '1') LIMIT 1 Completed in 58ms (View:
>   1, DB: 40) |
>   406 Not Acceptable [http://localhost/notifications/detect_type.json]

---

**here is a chrome request in the log:**

> Processing
>   NotificationsController#detect_type
>   (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-21 17:06:41)
>       [POST]   Parameters: {"action"=>"detect_type",
>   "content"=>"226 south emerson 80209",
>   "controller"=>"notifications"}
>       User Columns (2.1ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
>       User Load (30.4ms)
>       SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = '1') LIMIT 1 Completed
>   in 100ms (View: 1, DB: 33) |
>   200 OK [http://localhost/notifications/detect_type.json]

I'm stumped.  Ideas?

Comment: For anyone who might come across this , I had the exact same error in firefox , and then I realised I had javascript disabled in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, the solution was to do this on the rails side:

```
format.js {
  render :text => type.to_json
}
format.json {
  render :json => type.to_json
}
```

JQuery bug?  Not sure...

Comment: using "format.js" with "render :text => type.to_json" fixed it for me too... and I had already tried everything suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243345/406-not-acceptable-error-when-using-jquery-post-in-firefox-but-not-in-safari-or, without success

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick search it looks like perhaps 406 indicates a refusal by the browser (Firefox in this case) to accept the type of content being delivered from the server for the request.  [(This is one such explanation.)](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html)

Try configuring Firefox to accept json.  Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94767/debugging-my-web-app-with-json-firefox-firefox-handling-of-json) it looks like Firefox may want to use an extension...

**UPDATE**

Since this seems to be a straight use of $.ajax you should be able to get this to work without any odd Firefox client setting changes.  Try explicitly telling jquery what the type of data returned should be, by adding an option during init, like so:

> dataType: "json"

See the relevant jquery docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info.

Comment: I think this answer is on the right track... but I want to make this response just work for any firefox.... am I going to have to switch to XML?

Comment: you shouldn't have to; I'm able to use Firefox with $.ajax fine - try adding `dataType: "json"`; I'll add to my answer

Comment: dataType: "json" was one of the first things I tried.  Still get a 406.